# Unable to add the allegrograph plugin to topbraid composer

Tags: rdf, allegrograph, topbraid-composer

I am unable to add the allegrograph plugin to topbraid composer, getting the error message as

below:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: com.franz.agraph.feature 4.0.6.201212041354 (com.franz.agraph.feature.feature.group 4.0.6.201212041354)
  Missing requirement: AllegroGraph Query Plug-in 4.0.6.201212041354 (com.franz.agraph.query 4.0.6.201212041354) requires 'bundle org.topbraid.lib.sesame2 4.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: com.franz.agraph.feature 4.0.6.201212041354 (com.franz.agraph.feature.feature.group 4.0.6.201212041354)
    To: com.franz.agraph.query [4.0.6.201212041354]
```

Please let me know what to do to successfully add the allegrograph plugin to topbraid composer

Thanks in advance.

Mohan G

Answer (score 1):

What version of TBC and what version of the Plugin for TBC are you using?  Please send both with this error message to support@franz.com and we will get back to you and this forum with an answer.

Comment: I tried with TBC 4.1 and plugin is http://www.franz.com/ftp/pub/agraph/eclipse/tbc/4.1 .  and I tried 3.5 also. with this i am not getting error messeage. But at the time of exporting not getting the option AllegroGraph 4 Database Storage (*.ag4) to select.  Please help me regarding this. thanks